# Ruby / Rails - Can I use a joined table's scope(or class method) as part of my WHERE clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope, arel

I want to grab all the categories that contain purchaseable `products`.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  scope :purchaseable, where(:available => true)
end 

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  scope :with_purchaseable_products, ?????
end
```

So, I'm trying to define `:with_purchaseable_products`.  This works:

```
scope :with_purchaseable_products, joins(:products).where("products.available is true").group(:id).having('count(products.id) > 0')
```

But that's not very DRY.  Is there any way to apply my `:purchaseable` scope to `products` in my `:with_purchaseable_products` scope?

Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should use the merge method

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  scope :with_purchaseable_products, joins(:products).merge(Product.purchaseable).group(:id).having('count(products.id) > 0')
end
```

Read more on http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3

Comment: Two extra references: https://gorails.com/blog/activerecord-merge and http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge