# How to use a model scope on a .joins query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 2 models - User and User_detail.

Tables:

```
User
|id|

User_detail
|id|user_id|active|
```

UserDetails model:

```
class UserDetails < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    scope :active, -> { where("active is null or active = true") }
end
```

How can I use this scope in a query to get only the active users?

Something like this:

```
 User.joins(:user_details).active
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
User.joins(:user_details).merge(UserDetails.active)
```

Check out http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3 for more ActiveRecord tricks!

Comment: That looks like it's producing 2 separate queries: `User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN user_details ON user_details.user_id = users.id
  UserDetails Load (0.4ms)  SELECT user_details.* FROM user_details WHERE (active is null or active = true)`

Comment: It looks like the `&` shortcut has been removed. `merge` still works!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

`User.joins(:user_details).merge(UserDetails.active)`

Reference: [Ruby / Rails - Can I use a joined table's scope(or class method) as part of my WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852142/ruby-rails-can-i-use-a-joined-tables-scopeor-class-method-as-part-of-my-w)